# (Polymer) Cannot access last-response attribute of Iron Ajax request

Tags: javascript, json, data-binding, polymer

I am having some issues with data bindings. I am trying to load a JSON file using .

I need to access the values in the JSON file and bind them to properties in my element.

My request looks like this:

```
  <iron-ajax auto id="xmsprops"
          url="../../xms.json"
          handle-as="json"
          method="GET"
          on-response="onResponse"
          last-response="{{responseData}}"></iron-ajax>
```

Everything is returned and the data is present according to dev tools, however I am seemingly unable to access this data. The purpose is not to use the dom-repeat template, I just need to use the data in a few spots.

[This is the structure of my JSON file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSbgC.png)

I am pretty sure that I had this working in the past but cannot seem to locate the code, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
    <iron-ajax auto id="xmsprops"
          url="../../xms.json"
          handle-as="json"
          method="GET"
          on-response="onResponse"
          last-response="{{responseData}}"></iron-ajax>


<div>[[responseData.server_url]]</div>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing anything odd about the code you've posted there, I suspect the problem may lie elsewhere. Can you post the code for `onResponse`?

Comment: There actually is nothing in the 'onResponse' its just a console log so I know that it executed. I actually found this link which is essentially what I am trying to do, http://jsbin.com/funigo/2/edit?html,output . I have iron-ajax imported, I'm confused as to why this doesn't work.

Comment: In that case, can you post the code that monitors and accesses `responseData`? I suspect it is a race condition.

Comment: Still just testing so I am only just trying to display an attribute from the json file on the screen. Added under edit in main post. It just shows a blank div when I look in dev tools, no error message or anything.

Comment: Is this within a web component or on a regular page? If on a page, you will need to use `<template is="dom-bind">`.

Comment: It's in a custom component that is just being shown on the index.html page. There are a few paper-inputs and a button (nothing thats hooked up to anything yet.)

Comment: Here is a link to a paste bin of the element:  http://pastebin.com/LExzrMxG

Comment: I made a test component using roughly equivalent code to your pastebin and it worked as expected. I'm not sure how else to proceed with debugging short of having you host your component and its dependencies live somewhere. Have you run a `bower update`?

Comment: I ran the bower update, but still nothing.

Comment: I got it working, something goofy was happening behind the scenes. I just created a new project and it appears to be working fine.